# Is it possible to get the search term used by an Outlook instant search?

Tags: .net, search, outlook-2010

It's possible to use the Outlook interop libraries to perform an "instant search" using `Explorer.Search(query, scope)`, but is it possible to get the contents of a user-performed search, i.e. what has been typed into the "Search Inbox (Ctrl + E)" field at the top of the list of mail items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look possible. I also tried using Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.Filter, but, although this can be set, it's null when trying to read the instant search value.